# Can I use varargs in a retrofit method declaration?

Tags: java, retrofit

I've got an API endpoint that is defined as:

`GET https://api-server.com/something/{id_or_ids}`

where `ids` can be a **single object id *or* a comma separated list of ids**.
e.g.
`https://api-server.com/something/abcd1234`
`https://api-server.com/something/abcd1234,abcd4567,gdht64332`

if a **single id** is given (and a matching object is found) I get back a **json object**:
 
`{ "blah" : "blah" }`

If **multiple ids** are given, I get the response in a **json array**:
`[{"blah1":"bleh"}, {"blah2":"meh"}, {"blah3":"blah"}]`

I'm currently thinking that I should implement this as two methods (can it be done in one?):

one that *takes a single id and returns a single object*:

```
@GET("/something/{id}")
void getObject (@Path("id") String objectId, Callback<MyObject> callback)
```

*and*

one that *takes multiple ids and returns an array of objects*.

```
@GET("/something/{ids}")
void getObject (Callback<MyObject[]> callback,@Path("ids") String ... objectIds)
```

Is there a way to feed the 2nd method *varargs* and concatenate them in the id field?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrofit can't know how you want to join the strings in the path. While commas seem obvious, there's no reason why someone might want pipes (`|`) or colons (`:`) or whatever.

Because of this fact, we don't do anything and rely on you to choose.

There's two solutions to this:

- Use `String` as the argument type and join at the call site. For example:

  ```
  foo.getObject(Joiner.on(',').join(things));
  ```
- Use a custom object whose `toString()` method deals with returning the correct format for one or many objects.

Comment: Thanks Jake. Of course, I agree that any kind of join delimiter can be a valid use case. I thought there may be a *path transformer* type of solution where the default transformation is a `toString` but alternative transformations can be supplied (In this specific case a comma separator). I think I'll try the custom object alternative.